# JAVA save several DATE into a LIST using a custom Datatype

Tags: java, list, date

I want to save several periods of time, which look like that:

```
 public class periodOfTime {

    Date from;
    Date to; 
 }
```

into a List, which looks like that

```
List <periodOfTime> periodsOfTime = new List<periodOfTime>()
```

right now.

How can I store !FOR EXAMPLE!

`Date s = new Date();`

in my list?

My thoughts were, that it can be done with

```
periodsOfTime.add(s,s)
```

But it keeps on telling me

> The method add(int, periodOfTime) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (Date, Date)

Can anyone guide me?

Probably I am totally blind right now....

Comment: Obviously you cannot put `Date` object into a list of `periodOfTime` objects. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Maybe you need `periodsOfTime.add(new periodOfTIme())`?

Comment: study basics of jva.util.List again and u will come to know...u have to add periodOfTime() to that ...check the add method signature here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to make getters and setters:)

Try:

```
PeriodOfTime period = new Period();
period.from = date;
period.to = another_date;
```

and add to for example **ArrayList**:

```
periodsOfTime.add(period);
```

It will help.